# How to convert a list with multiple types to binary in Python?

Tags: python

I have an array with two elements: the first is type, the second is a data array I need to convert.

```
[['string','int32','string','int64','float32','string','string'],['any string','19','any string','198732132451654654','0.6','any string','any string']]
```

I know how to convert integer to binary, but in the above array with multiple types, how do I convert it to binary?

Comment: What are you trying to do? id(o) will give 'binary' representation of an object (physical address) - but I'm sure it is not what you want

Comment: Your second list is a bunch of strings. So your question is how do you cast the second list based on the types in the first list?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, i need convert "the second list based on the types in the first list" into binary data, (use struct.pack) in python. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've accepted my other answer, after noticing your comment explaining that what you really wanted was to convert the data into binary using `struct.pack()`, I've written another that might suit you even better (despite being longer and a little more complicated).

```
import struct

class TypeConv(object):
    BSA = '='  # native Byte order, standard Size, with no Alignment
    def __init__(self, conv_func, fmt_chr):
        self.__dict__.update(conv_func=conv_func, fmt_chr=fmt_chr)

    def pack(self, data):
        py_value = self.conv_func(data)
        count = str(len(py_value)) if self.conv_func is str else ''
        return struct.pack(self.BSA+count+self.fmt_chr, py_value)

type_conv = {'string': TypeConv(str, 's'),
             'int32': TypeConv(int, 'i'),
             'int64': TypeConv(long, 'q'),
             'float32': TypeConv(float, 'f'),
            }

array = [['string', 'int32', 'string', 'int64', 'float32', 'string', 'string'],
         ['any string', '19', 'any string', '198732132451654654',
          '0.6', 'any string', 'any string']]

binary_values = [type_conv[type_id].pack(data)
                     for type_id, data in zip(array[0], array[1])
                         if type_id in type_conv]  # to skip any unknown type_ids
print binary_values
```

Output:

```
['any string', '\x13\x00\x00\x00', 'any string', '\xfe\x9b<P\xd2\t\xc2\x02',
 '\x9a\x99\x19?', 'any string', 'any string']
```

The `TypeConv.pack()` method first converts the string value to its equivalent Python value `py_value`, then uses `struct.pack()` to convert that to a C binary value -- which I think is what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good way to do it:

```
data = [['string','int32','string','int64','float32','string','string'],
        ['any string','19','any string','198732132451654654','0.6',
         'any string','any string']]

type_map = {'string': str, 'int32': int, 'int64': long, 'float32': float}
results = [type_map[t](d) for t, d in zip(data[0], data[1])]
print results
```

Results:

```
['any string', 19, 'any string', 198732132451654654L, 0.6, 'any string', 'any string']
```

This creates the result list by looking up a conversion function in the `type_map` dictionary using the type string as a key for each item in the first list, and then calls it with the corresponding data item from the second list. Lists can be created with a `for` loop right in a list declaration by using something called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehension#grammar-token-list_comprehension). The `zip` function is used here to create pairs of values from each sublist for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want or not, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
casts = { 'string': lambda x: str(x), \
    'int32': lambda x: int(x), \
    'int64': lambda x: int(x), \
    'float32': lambda x: float(x) }

types_to_cast = [['string','int32','string','int64','float32','string','string'],['any string','19','any string','198732132451654654','0.6','any string','any string']]

print [casts[types_to_cast[0][i]](types_to_cast[1][i]) for i in range(len(types_to_cast[0]))]
```

Comment: The extra overhead of the `lambda` functions in the `casts` dictionary is unnecessary since all they do is call another function. FWIW I've generally found that whenever I find myself using a `for i in range(...)` to consider it a signal that there are very likely a more "Pythonic" -- and probably shorter and more readable -- ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the advise.