# Pythonic way to convert a list with multiple types (including lists!)

Tags: python, casting, type-conversion

Given a list of tokens and a proper, known type representation of those tokens, how do I map the type onto the list? If the types are `int`'s or `floats` I can call `int(x)` over a string to convert the value into an int, but this fails if my type is a `list` (or say a `numpy.array`). What is the most pythonic way to do the conversion? `eval` is not an option here as the data is essentially unsanitized. An example:

```
line     = "0 0 62.9695 [16.859,-17.1135,46.6351] [7.1759,29.3009,83.1399]"
tokens   = line.split()
type_key = [int,int,float,list,list] # Lists do not convert properly here

print [T(x) for T,x in zip(type_key,tokens)]
```

Related: [How to convert a list with multiple types to binary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979931/how-to-convert-a-list-with-multiple-types-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: Alternatively, do you have any other choice as to how you get the data? (You could ask for it in YAML, for instance, or JSON or any other sane markup format.

Comment: @katrielalex +1, it's always better to rely on a well defined markup language in situations like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which was designed for this purpose.

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("[16.859,-17.1135,46.6351]")
[16.859, -17.1135, 46.6351]
```

Edit: As per the problem in your comment:

```
def literal_eval_to_array(literal):
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(literal))
```

Then you can simply use `literal_eval_to_array()` in your `type_key` - remember that a function call and instantiation are the same to Python.

Comment: Great, that solves the problem of the lists! What if, for example, my type_map looks something like `[int, float, np.array]`? Would the lists have to be converted to `np.array`'s "by hand" after ast parsed them into lists?

Comment: @hooked Nope, simply define a function that does the evaluation and conversion, and use that. I'll give an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way for you would be to create a map of type to converter functions and then you can have as complex a converter as you want e.g.

```
import ast
def convert_list(str_val):
    return ast.literal_eval(str_val)

def convert_array(str_val):
    # do something here
    return []

converter_map = {
    list: convert_list,
    'np.array': convert_array
}

def convert(str_val, _type):
    converter = _type
    if _type in converter_map:
        converter = converter_map[_type]
    return converter(str_val)

line     = "0 0 62.9695 [16.859,-17.1135,46.6351] [7.1759,29.3009,83.1399]"
type_key = [int,int,float,list,list] 

print [convert(v, t) for v, t in zip(line.split(), type_key)]
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 62.969499999999996, [16.859000000000002, -17.113499999999998, 46.635100000000001], [7.1759000000000004, 29.300899999999999, 83.139899999999997]]
```

This makes it a very flexible scheme and you can sanitize and process your inputs in a very flexible way

Comment: This is a massive overcomplication - why not just give the conversion functions instead of the types in the second list? Also note ``convert()`` can be simplified to ``converter_map.get(type, type)(value)``.

Comment: @Lattyware, I wanted to decouple that because I am not sure from where those types are coming and if writer of code has control over it e.g. if some file defines values and types, so I provided a generic solution not complicated

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that if he can't get the data in any format other than a string, getting the types as Python types seems unlikely if he is getting them from an unknown source.